# Ionic app with option to attend facebook events

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework

I'm doing a hybrid app using Ionic framework. 
I want to implement a facebook event system to attend some events. I have this:

```
         ngFB.api(
                    '/666945880120392/attending',
                    'GET',
                    {},
                    function(response) {
                        // Insert your code here
                    }
                );
```

and I have ngFB in my app.js file like this:

```
ngFB.init({appId: '[APP_ID]'});
```

The error I have is:

```
openfb.js:256 GET https://graph.facebook.comundefined/?access_token=undefined net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

I was looking for a solution but no answer. I also try in the developer facebook console and the answer is correct:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=666945880120392%2Fattending&version=v2.7

What it's happening? Thanks!

***EDIT 1***

Thanks to @e666 I did now this

```
ngFB.api({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/666945880120392/attending'
}).then(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

And the error now is that if I'm logged with an account always the return in the event is:

```
Object {data: Array[1], paging: Object}
```

And inside data is the name of another person, the unique person that is attending to the event and no the person who is logged with the access token.
Thanks!

***EDIT 2***

I opened another question because this is not the result than I hope, I need to go to an event, no to get the list of the people that goes to the event.
I have this now:

```
ngFB.api(
                    "/666945880120392/attending",
                    function (response) {
                        if (response && !response.error) {
                            console.dir(response);
                        }
                    }
                );
```

the access_token is ok, and the response is

```
openfb.js:256 GET https://graph.facebook.comundefined/?access_token=EAABlK6y7pOUBAN3CPWdZB5FL…LCpXL9Bd3ELHQZAA6EJc6cCheAxUUnL59ZCZAf7aROCapJxiu991fxjDkxmMO651rfuREwZDZD net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

In the page of facebook https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=666945880120392%2Fattending&version=v2.5

The response is

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#299) Requires extended permission: rsvp_event",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 299,
    "fbtrace_id": "G7HFJ48pbkx"
  }
}
```

But I have this permission. Can someone help me please?

Comment: the api endpoint includes "undefined". debug ngFB.api and see why that happens.

Comment: @luschn How can I debug it?

Comment: Was it working on graph api ? Because the api you use is only available on reading and doing a get request to attend an event seem weird. Please read facebook docs : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/attending. Also, I am not sure that you should continue to use this post. Since the issue has changed. You have resolved one.

Comment: @e666 I think is not resolved because is not working like I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the path is undefined because you don't use correctly the method `api`. That is how you need to use it :

```
ngFB.api({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/666945880120392/attending'
}).then(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Furthermore, you have undefined in `access_token`. As I looked in the library code, I am not sure that you can use this library without login as a user to have an `access_token`.

To have an `access_token` you need to use this function :

```
ngFB.login({scope: 'email'}).then(function(response) {
   console.log('Access token' + response.authResponse.accessToken);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

The `access_token` will then be automatically attached to request that you make with `OpenFB`.

You can find more complete examples of how to use the library is the github here : https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB/blob/master/indexng.html

Comment: Yes, I have an access_token when the user loggin in the app, but where I have to put it? Thanks a million

Comment: I have completed my answer.

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm login with cordovaOauth and maybe in the ngFB is not the access_token. Is it any way to attend an event using cordovaOauth? Thanks a million

Comment: If you already have an access_token, you can pass it through init method :   `ngFB.init({appId: '[APP_ID]', accessToken: accessToken});`